# Получить value из HTML тега

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, есть HTML код:

```
<input type="hidden"     id="tracking__token" name="tracking[_token]"        class="form-control" value="Abracadabra111" >
```

Каким образом можно получить "Abracadabra111"?. Я использовал `regexp` `/value=\"/`, но в итоге получил ещё и лишнее - `" >`.

Comment: Как насчет использования DOMDocument? Такой вариант (правильный) рассматривается?

Comment: @stribizhev рассматривается :) (а если можно через simple_html_dom, то ещё лучше)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вам предложу такую регулярку:

```
~value="(.*?)"~
```

Она сработает. `*?` - любое количество символов (в нашем случае любых), но как можно меньше (то есть до первой `"`).

Весь код ниже. Там более хитрое регулярное выражение:

```
~<(?:.*?)value="(.*?)"(?:.*?)>~s
```

Оно описывает поиск только внутри тегов, а `s` модификатор позволяет искать в многострочном тексте. Вот тут посмотрите https://regex101.com/r/qB9gS3/1 сайт подробно рассказывает что к чему (правда на английском).

```
        $str = '<input type="hidden"  id="tracking__token" name="tracking[_token]" class="form-control" value="AJKY99B2mC__AP7vPza111" >';
        preg_match_all('~<(?:.*?)value="(.*?)"(?:.*?)>~s', $str, $matches);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($matches as $match)
        {
            foreach ($match as $item)
            {
                echo "$i: ", htmlentities($item), "<br>";
            }
            $i++;                    
        }
```

Вывод:

```
0: <input type="hidden" id="tracking__token" name="tracking[_token]" class="form-control" value="AJKY99B2mC__AP7vPza111" >
1: AJKY99B2mC__AP7vPza111
```

UPD: можно еще пробел добавить `'~<(?:.*?)\svalue="(.*?)"(?:.*?)>~s'`

Answer (score 0):

совсем не понятно, как вы могли хоть что-то получить этим `regexp`. в самом простом случае должно быть как-то так:

```
 /value=\"(.+)\"/
```

или еще лучше вот так:

```
/value=\"([[:alnum:]]+)\"/
```

ну и вы же в курсе, что вернется массив, в котором нужно смотреть [1]-й индекс, а не [0]?

Comment: Индекс 0: `<input type="hidden"     id="tracking__token" name="tracking[_token]"        class="form-control" value="JKY992esIt7vpuT9ZYqwfk99pibSJwB2mC__AP7vPzM" >`, индекс 1: `>`

Comment: а, ну так вы бы сказали, что там еще другие символы бывают, кроме букв и цифр. а первый вариант, который я предложил? вообще-то без знания синтаксиса `regexp`, хотя бы базового, в программировании никуда. книжку хоть одну надо прочитать, а чтобы практиковаться, вот ресурс: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Помню парсил страницы с помощью XPath запросов, их основное направление XML, но и HTML можно обработать. Вот ссылка на [статью на Хабрахабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114772/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin хорошо, в следующий раз не буду так делать)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), попробуйте

```
$str = '<input type="hidden"     id="tracking__token" name="tracking[_token]"        class="form-control" value="Abracadabra111" >';
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find('input[id=tracking__token]') as $element) 
   echo $element->value;`
```

---

Вот еще пример:

```
$html = '<input type="hidden"     id="tracking__token" name="tracking[_token]"        class="form-control" value="Abracadabra111" >';

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$searchNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName("input"); 
foreach($searchNode as $s) 
{ 
    if ($s->getAttribute("name") == "tracking[_token]") {
      $value = $s->getAttribute('value');
      echo "$value\n"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/<input\s+[^>]*?\s*value=(["'])?(.*?)\1/
```

Взять вторую группу.